# How is the dataset divided in kfold cross validation with differing values of k?

Tags: python, cross-validation, k-fold

This is the basic code I used with varying values of k (3,4,5,6)

```
from numpy import array
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
# data sample type(data)
data = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6])
# prepare cross validation
k = 6
kfold = KFold(k, True, 1)
# enumerate splits
for train, test in kfold.split(data):
    print('train: %s, test: %s' % (data[train], data[test]))
```

The Outputs are: -

```
k = 3
train: [0.1 0.4 0.5 0.6], test: [0.2 0.3]
train: [0.2 0.3 0.4 0.6], test: [0.1 0.5]
train: [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.5], test: [0.4 0.6]

k=4
train: [0.1 0.4 0.5 0.6], test: [0.2 0.3]
train: [0.2 0.3 0.4 0.6], test: [0.1 0.5]
train: [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.5 0.6], test: [0.4]
train: [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5], test: [0.6]

k=5
train: [0.1 0.4 0.5 0.6], test: [0.2 0.3]
train: [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.6], test: [0.5]
train: [0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6], test: [0.1]
train: [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.5 0.6], test: [0.4]
train: [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5], test: [0.6]

k=6
train: [0.1 0.2 0.4 0.5 0.6], test: [0.3]
train: [0.1 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6], test: [0.2]
train: [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.6], test: [0.5]
train: [0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6], test: [0.1]
train: [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.5 0.6], test: [0.4]
train: [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5], test: [0.6]
```

One common thing in all of them is that validation set never repeats an observation however, the definition, "Each fold is then used once as a validation while the k - 1 remaining folds form the training set". is wrong for k=3,4,5 and only k=6 is correct then, right?

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because your input data doesn't always create perfect splits except when k=3 or k=6.

> The first n_samples % n_splits folds have size n_samples // n_splits + 1, other folds have size n_samples // n_splits, where n_samples is the number of samples.

You've 6 samples:

1. k=3: first 6%3(=0) folds have size 6//3+1(=3), rest have size 6//3(=2).
2. k=4: first 6%4(=2) folds have size 6//4+1(=2), rest have size 1//4(=1).

and so on...

> Each fold is then used once as a validation while the k - 1 remaining folds form the training set.

This is what's happening here e.g. for k=3 (3 folds being `[0.2 0.3], [0.1 0.5], [0.4 0.6]`), in first iteration, `[0.2 0.3]` is used as validation and `[0.1 0.5 0.4 0.6]` as training.